# Python: ValueError '3' is not in list

Tags: python, valueerror

I'm new to programming and I don't understand this error. I have a program that is supposed to tell you the numerical position of an alphabet from a given letter input. If the input is not an alphabet it should return 'does not belong to the alphabet'. However I'm getting a ValueError when giving a number input.

The code I'm working on:

```
alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','å','ä','ö']

myAlphabet = input("Enter the letter you are looking for in the alphabet:")
Number0OfA = alphabets.index(myAlphabet)

for myAlphabet in alphabets:
    if myAlphabet in alphabets:
        print(myAlphabet ,'is the', Number0OfA, '. alphabet')
        break
    else:
        print(myAlphabet , 'does not belong to the alphabet')
```

The error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
'3' is not in list
  File "C:\Users\me\pycode\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    Number0OfA = alphabets.index(myAlphabet)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You do not need the loop, you already have the index.

Comment: Well, you appear to have entered "3". Which is not in the list…

Comment: Your list of alphabets doesn't have numbers, so when you try to enter a number python  searches it in the list and then finally tells you that `3 is not in the list` with a `ValueError`

Comment: use `if` to check if input entered is in the list first,`if myAlphabet in alphabets: Number0OfA = alphabets.index(myAlphabet)` `else: print("not found")`

Comment: @sittsering `try: index = alphabets.index(mA) except ValueError: print('Not found')`…

Comment: The `index` method on the line `Number0OfA = alphabets.index(myAlphabet)` is used incorrectly. You should use the `index` method to returns the index of the value. If the value is not present it will return ValueError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for failure is, your `list` does not contain `3`, and hence when `index()` tries to get the location of `3` it does not find it and hence says `ValueError`.
There's actually no need of a `for` loop. It can simply be done using `in` as below:

```
alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','å','ä','ö']

myAlphabet = input("Enter the letter you are looking for in the alphabet:")
if myAlphabet in alphabets:
    print(myAlphabet ,'is the', alphabets.index(myAlphabet), '. alphabet')
else:
    print(myAlphabet , 'does not belong to the alphabet')
```

However if you still want to use a for loop, below is the way:

```
alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','å','ä','ö']

myAlphabet = input("Enter the letter you are looking for in the alphabet:")
if myAlphabet not in alphabets:
    print (myAlphabet , 'does not belong to the alphabet')
else:
    for index in range(len(alphabets)): 
        if myAlphabet == alphabets[index]:
            print(myAlphabet ,'is the', index, '. alphabet')
            break
```

Output:

```
Enter the letter you are looking for in the alphabet:z
z is the 25 . alphabet
```

Answer (score 1):

.index returns the index of an entry of the list. So alphabets.index("a") returns 0. Use alphabets[int(myAlphabet)] instead.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to loop at all:

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + 'åäö' # long string with all letters

def print_in_alphabet(c, alphabet=alphabet):
    # alphabet.index throws exception when value not found
    try:
        index = alphabet.index(c)
        print(f'Letter {c} found at index {index} in alphabet')
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Letter {c} not found in alphabet')

print_in_alphabet('c') # Letter c found at index 2 in alphabet
print_in_alphabet('3') # Letter 3 not found in alphabet
```